# 0x batchFillLimitOrders not working with small remainingFillableTakerAmount

Tags: 0x

I am experiencing issues filling orders using the `batchFillLimitOrders` function when the `remainingFillableTakerAmount` is small.

I am calling the following piece of code using the input parameters listed below:

```
const response = await exchange
      .batchFillLimitOrders(fillOrders, signatures, takerAssetFillAmounts, true)
      .awaitTransactionSuccessAsync({ from: orderData.maker })
      .catch((err) => console.error('Error logged ' + JSON.stringify(err)))
```

First input parameter: Order objects

```
[
{
  chainId: 3
  expiry: "1657831517"
  feeRecipient: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  maker: "0x4c12ab430e078c56010c46f9391c60be50781b07"
  makerAmount: "270000000000000000000"
  makerToken: "0x134e62bd2ee247d4186a1fdbaa9e076cb26c1355"
  pool: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  remainingFillableTakerAmount: "9998758480790449"
  salt: "1655239517688"
  sender: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  taker: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  takerAmount: "10000000000000000"
  takerToken: "0x03582cb41f2fd982e1b531d633b6de049d56f2a0"
  takerTokenFeeAmount: "0"
  verifyingContract: "0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff"
},
{
  chainId: 3
  expiry: "1656397720"
  feeRecipient: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  maker: "0x2db4625a9ece077cb432d1a84b85b03c15721be6"
  makerAmount: "225300000000000000000"
  makerToken: "0x134e62bd2ee247d4186a1fdbaa9e076cb26c1355"
  pool: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  remainingFillableTakerAmount: "1"
  salt: "1655188120250"
  sender: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  taker: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  takerAmount: "100000000000000000"
  takerToken: "0x03582cb41f2fd982e1b531d633b6de049d56f2a0"
  takerTokenFeeAmount: "0"
  verifyingContract: "0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff"
},
{
  chainId: 3
  expiry: "1655274128"
  feeRecipient: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  maker: "0x2a65ae527c6ff4665e048b0e0883c486a7ba4dbc"
  makerAmount: "67200000000000000000"
  makerToken: "0x134e62bd2ee247d4186a1fdbaa9e076cb26c1355"
  pool: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  remainingFillableTakerAmount: "2922902068498283"
  salt: "1655230928557"
  sender: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  taker: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  takerAmount: "3000000000000000"
  takerToken: "0x03582cb41f2fd982e1b531d633b6de049d56f2a0"
  takerTokenFeeAmount: "0"
  verifyingContract: "0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff"
}
]
```

Second input parameter: Signatures

```
[
{
  r: "0x30feaab607cbc25f0f672f42f91bfc9c2946d14ba46014808196aade6b9bf63d"
  s: "0x4e56d337898ac32854588023f1347ac0904e2bcc887598f9495b3b3b96ec6fd0"
  signatureType: 2
  v: 27
},
{
  r: "0x41bd89be774e218d88801f474d38344eeb76e2c6603e41869a0041d91aba21ec"
  s: "0x75e28c241a60f9b83ac88d696819218728998805615ab67843e7044acab33476"
  signatureType: 2
  v: 27
},
{
  r: "0x214b1450334bafa9b3e1c48c3e31f82916662e4b53045b8515655074edadfdbc"
  s: "0x7d1005a5473a886ba0b6aae64d88a9d30fe8e88a957332eb155e97b1e69ddacc"
  signatureType: 2
  v: 28
}
]
```

Third input parameter: TakerAssetFillAmounts

```
[
'9998758480790449',
'1',
'1241519209550'
]
```

Error message that I receive:

```
{"code":-32603,"message":"execution reverted","data":{"originalError":{"code":3,"data":"0x1d44aa5dc35b019348a46f24084407a1a39c446af5cfef56fe27d475d0285d3861f0fe0a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002385d15f7143b1","message":"execution reverted"}}}
```

The weird thing is that it works if I deduct 1 from each TakerAssetFillAmount element, i.e. if I pass the following as the third parameter:

```
[
'9998758480790448',
'0',
'1241519209549'
]
```

This let's me assume that there might be some rounding issue in the 0x protocol itself or the 0x API.

I looked at the smart contract implementation of the `batchFillLimitOrder` function and I suspect that it ends up in the `catch` without throwing any meaningful error message.

[image]

The consequence of this problem is that I cannot get rid of the dust transactions in the following orderbook that we built on top of 0x protocol: https://app.diva.finance/91/long

Anyone here who could help?

**Another example that is failing:**

Order:

```
chainId: 3
expiry: "1656539073"
feeRecipient: "0xbb0f479895915f80f6feb5babcb0ad39a0d7ef4e"
maker: "0x9adefeb576dcf52f5220709c1b267d89d5208d78"
makerAmount: "10000000000000000000"
makerToken: "0x8218c91a4d06829de73200201db7f57f1f7e698e"
pool: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
remainingFillableTakerAmount: "5000000000000000000"
salt: "1655934273929"
sender: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
taker: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
takerAmount: "5000000000000000000"
takerToken: "0x134e62bd2ee247d4186a1fdbaa9e076cb26c1355"
takerTokenFeeAmount: "50000000000000000"
verifyingContract: "0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff"
```

Trying to fill `3500000000000000000` out of `5000000000000000000` (i.e. 3.5 out of 5.0 remaining) results in the same error. Reducing the fill amount to `3450000000000000000` works though.

I checked the allowance for the takerToken for the address that I am using (`0x47566C6c8f70E4F16Aa3E7D8eED4a2bDb3f4925b`) and it shows `3500000000000000000` so this can't be the reasons as suspected in one of the comments.

I'd like to understand why this keeps happening and what I can do to mitigate that problem.

**Update**

It looks that if the approved amount is equal to `remainingFillableTakerAmount`, then it fails. It seems that approving slightly more than the `remainingFillableTakerAmount` does the trick. But would be curious to understand why.

Comment: Can you provide the `blockNumber` you were attempting to fill these orders at? Additionally, the `takerAddress` in question would also be helpful. Using a tool like Tenderly, we should be able to track down the reason for the revert.

Comment: `takerAddress`: 0x9AdEFeb576dcF52F5220709c1B267d89d5208D78
I cannot provide a `blockNumber` as the transaction isn't even initiated.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something but have you tried seeing whether there's anything specific to your second order (the one with  remainingFillableTakerAmount: "1").

E.g. does this work?

```
[
'9998758480790449',
'1',
'1241519209550'
]
```

Comment: The reason for `remainingFillableTakerAmount = '1'` is because due to the issue that we are experiencing, we are deducting 1 from each takerAssetFillAmount. As a result, you end up with 1 being the `remainingFillableTakerAmount` which we end up filtering out from our orderbook.

Answer (score 0):

Also, can you double-check if the approval or a balance may have been insufficient for one of the tokens?
A simulation of your order is throwing an error that ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance.

Comment: I checked with my 0x boilerplate code and there is sufficient allowance. You can try it out here yourself: https://github.com/Walodja1987/0x-fill-order-example/blob/main/src/BatchFillOrders.js

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out my issue. If `takerTokenFeeAmount > 0`, then it looks like the taker needs to approve the sum, i.e. `takerAmount + takerTokenFee` and not just `takerAmount`. Hope this helps anyone who is working with the 0x protocol.